# Display image in php

Tags: php, html, mysql, blob

I have a problem trying to display an image from a mysql blob

my first file is image.php

this code:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM foto where fk_pro_id = ".$id_pro." 
                      ORDER BY id DESC", $conexio);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {    
    echo '<li>';
    echo '<a href="javascript:;" id="'.$row['id'].'">';
    echo '<img src="../images/delete.png"/></a>';

 echo '<img src="show_image.php?id='.$row['id'].'"/>'; 
  //i call this file to find the images

    echo '<span>'.$row['id'].'</span>';
    echo '</li>';
}
```

the second file is show_image.php

```
    $id =  mysql_escape_string($_GET['id']);
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM foto WHERE id = $id", $conexio);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{    
   $imagen = $row['fotografia'];
       $tipo   = $row['tipo'];
   header("content-type: $tipo"); 
   echo    $imagen;
}
```

the problem is when i trying show the image.. appears as if this a broke link..

Thanks!!

Comment: I've got my money on `header("content-type: $tipo");`

Comment: What's the response header "content-type"?

Comment: the second code worked and showed the picture if called directly, also did a test from a html and also showed the image. i do not where is the problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem lies within `header("content-type: $tipo");`

Change it to `header("Content-Type: $tipo");` and ensure that $tipo returns valid a Content-Type (MIME type) i.e. image/png etc. you can find a list [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME_type)

Comment: thanks for the answer.. the database return the file type i.e image/png,image/jpg i stored this value in $tipo..

Comment: @IsaiasDavidAnzolaGarces Try and do `var_dump($imagen);` or `print_r($imagen);` and see what you get back (place it inside your running code). Also make sure your DB isn't adding anything to `image/png`

Comment: @IsaiasDavidAnzolaGarces So what was the problem and how did you solve it?

Comment: my first problem was the database in my variable $tipo was not stored the right mime type...

Comment: @IsaiasDavidAnzolaGarces As my answer helped you, I would appreciate it if you marked it as correct.